# Changes to initializers in Ember 1.12.0

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember CLI and have read the 1.12.0 release blog entry here:

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html#toc_instance-initializers

and this article:

http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers

but although I believe I have followed the instructions correctly I am still getting the following deprecation warning:

> DEPRECATION: `lookupFactory` was called on a Registry. The
>   `initializer` API no longer receives a container, and you should use
>   an `instanceInitializer` to look up objects from the container. See
>   http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers
>   for more details.

I have an initializer that injects a service called "ui" and therefore I believe it to be an application initializer rather than an instance initializer (though I have tried both). My initializer code sits under /app/initializers/ui.js and is as follows:

```
export function initialize(registry, application) {
    application.inject('route', 'ui', 'service:ui');
    application.inject('controller', 'ui', 'service:ui');
}

export default {
    name: 'ui',
    initialize: initialize
};
```

Can anyone advise me what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks!

UPDATE: It looks like others are having similar issues:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11172

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/dependancy-injection-in-initializers-confusing-registry-container/7972/2

Comment: Put them under the folder 'instance-initializers'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241691/using-instance-initializers-with-ember-1-12-0-and-the-ember-cli

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my initializer is not an instance initializer as it is being used purely to inject a service. In the links mentioned above it says these are application initializers which belong in the "initializers" folder. I did try the folder you suggested but it made no difference.

Comment: It looks like there's an open issue for this on ember data: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3051

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by recent updates so no longer an issue. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: danr1979 could you give more details how did you solve it? Thanks

Comment: Hi. I just updated to the latest version at the time (1.13 I think) & that fixed it.  The deprecation message was being shown in error in my case.